# How to create a DataFrame of the mean of an inner level of a pandas DataFrame multi-column index with identical names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, let's say I have a two-leveled pandas DataFrame as follows, with Cluster as level 0 and subcluster as level 1 in the multi-index:

```
Cluster        1         2         3
subcluster  1  1  2   1  2  2   1   2   3

A           11 12 13  13 20 21  16 127 18
B           14 15 16  14 19 22  16 027 19
C           17 18 19  15 18 23  16 71  12
D           20 21 22  16 17 24  16 71  30
```

What I'd like to be able to do is create a DataFrame consisting of the mean value of each subcluster. Note that some of the subclusters are named the same due to the nomenclature of the dataset(for examplee, both cluster 1 and 2 each have two different subclustersa, as seen above. My actual dataset is much bigger, with 15 different clusters and a maximum of 29 subclusters, totalling around 40 000 columns.

Using `df.groupby(level=1, axis=1).mean()` doesn't work since it doesn't discriminate between cluster 1 subcluster 1 and cluster 2 subcluster 1, for example, which I'd like to do. In other words, it'd create a DataFrame of means that only has 3 columns, one for each subcluster whereas I'd like to limit it to find the means of each subcluster within its cluster. Using `df[1].groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean()` does the job as far as I can tell, but that means that I have to do it for each of the 15 clusters and then concatenate all of them to end up where I want.

My question is if there's a quicker, more elegant way of doing it. Also, preferably a way that retains information about the cluster of origin. My way of doing it doesn't show the main cluster, meaning that I have to manually add that to each of the DataFrame before concatenation.

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: What is expected output with numbers, e.g. first row?

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate? I'm not sure that I'm understanding what you're asking, but what I'm interested in is the row mean, i.e. for each subcluster, finding the mean for each of A, B, C and D.

Comment: I ask for expected output, e.g first row is 10,20,50, plase change values by input data.

Comment: For the first row, the output would be: Cluster 1 (11.5 13), Cluster 2 (13, 20.5) and Cluster 3 (16, 127, 18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mean` with specify both levels:

```
df1 = df.mean(axis=1, level=[0,1])
```

It is same like:

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=[0,1], axis=1).mean()
```

---

```
print (df1)
Cluster     1           2           3             
            1     2     1     2     1      2     3
A        11.5  13.0  13.0  20.5  16.0  127.0  18.0
B        14.5  16.0  14.0  20.5  16.0   27.0  19.0
C        17.5  19.0  15.0  20.5  16.0   71.0  12.0
D        20.5  22.0  16.0  20.5  16.0   71.0  30.0
```